# How can I save the array in the same field in the database using the following "|" as seperator?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is a drag and drop code it's getting saved in the database individually. I want to give my users facility to save their dashboard layout according to their choice. Please look at the following image and if you have any suggestions let me know. Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
    **index.php**
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 

            $(function() {
                $("#contentLeft #db_boxes").sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function() {
                    var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=updateRecordsListings'; 
                    $.post("updateDB.php", order, function(theResponse){
                        $("#contentRight").html(theResponse);
                    });                                                              
                }                                 
                });
            });

        }); 
        </script>

    **updateDB.php**

    <?php 
    require("db.php");
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    $action = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['action']); 
    $updateRecordsArray = $_POST['recordsArray'];

    if ($action == "updateRecordsListings"){

        $listingCounter = 1;
        foreach ($updateRecordsArray as $recordIDValue) {

            $query = "UPDATE dnd_records SET recordListingID = " . $listingCounter . " WHERE username = " . $username;
            mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
            $listingCounter = $listingCounter + 1;  
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($updateRecordsArray);
        echo '</pre>';

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Why do you want to apply the anti-pattern?

Comment: I guess this is not the best database structure. SQL is relational, you'd better use foreign keys for that.

Comment: have a look at json_encode, json_decode, this should do what your looking for, better for saving array structures to one row in your database, encode before saving to db, then decode, when using them

Comment: I don't see how the actual problem has anything to do with PHP, JavaScript, jQuery or Ajax.

Comment: Read on [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and why you should not break it.

Comment: "Suggestions"? What is your question.

Answer (score 1):

Denormalizing a database that way usually isn't a good idea, but of course we don't know your particular use case.

If you want to do it, you can use the `join` function on an array to get a string with the elements of the array joined together using a given delimiter. You can do this either at the JavaScript end (using [`Array#join`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.5)) or the PHP end using [`join`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) (an alias of [`implode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)).

Comment: Usually the `particular use case` is *I do not know how to handle multiple rows returned from database so I would like them to be returned in one mashed up record and I will parse them using `explode()`*, or similar. If any use case would require **denormalized** databases, **it is a bad use case** and should be rethinked...

Comment: basically I don't want to insert 7 records for every diff user. that's why to have only 1 row for a particular user.

Comment: @colourtheweb And that's the bad idea... But still, a much better solution to this is to create an array of the values, serialize them and then store a serialized string. Hmm?

Answer (score 0):

My opinion: do not model **denormalized** databases. NEVER. If You think You need to do that, You are thinking in bad manner. Think again and do it better. Don't You know how to work with multiple rows (records) returned in JavaScript? Or even in PHP? Well, ask about *How to handle multiple rows returned from SQL query* then. We will advise You to use `foreach()` or `while()` loops.

If it is a JavaScript problem, then return/send a JSON array to Your JavaScript script and again - use a **loop** to go through the records...

Storing data joined through `|` or `;` is very old and very bad compulsion - if You saw it somewhere, forget about it immediately and learn a better new stuff - [Database normal forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

**EDIT:**
If You still need to store such balast data, do it in better way - serialize them in array/object:

```
$array = array('One', 'Two', 'Three');
$serialized = serialize($array);
// output something like: a:3:{s:3:One;s:3:Two;s:5:Three}
```

Store this `$serialized` string into the database rather than `One|Two|Three` value... After retrieveing from database call:

```
$array = unserialize($serialized);
```

If it is up to updating the row:

1. retrieve the row
2. unserialize
3. add to/modify the array
4. serialize
5. save

Comment: mate i understand your point but the thing is this is a drag and drop code where the heading and the ids of the boxes are same.. whats different is the positiong id and the username. So what i dont want is to create 7 rows in the database for the same user. It's like creating the for no reason that's the reason why I thought why not save it in one row and at the time of display just explode the aaray anddisplay the drag n drop boxes position accordingly.

Comment: As I commented above - much less overkill will be to store the serialized string (from an array, e.g.)... Think about it...

Comment: if you don't mind can u give me an example ?

Comment: thnx! really appreciate it